# Arbitrage sports betting

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, gambling

> Player A vs Player B.
>
> - Bookie 1 offers 1.36 odds on player A winning.
> - Bookie 2 offers 5.5 on player B winning.
>
> We have $1000 in total to bet. How would you place your bets such that profit is maximized?

I have been told that this can be solved using linear programming, but I don't know how to set the problem up properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bet $0 \leq x \leq 1000$ at the first bookie and $1000 - x$ at the second bookie. The goal is to maximize

$$\min \{ 1.36 x - 1000, 4500 - 5.5 x \}$$

which is the inverted "V" depicted below

[image]

The maximum is attained when

$$1.36 x - 1000 = 4500 - 5.5 x$$

The maximum is $\approx 90$, which is attained at $x \approx 802$.

There is no need to use linear programming. However, if you really, *really* do want to use linear programming, then solve the following linear program in $x$ and $t$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & 1.36 x - 1000 \geq t\\ & 4500 - 5.5 x \geq t\\ & 0 \leq x \leq 1000\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks, this makes it super clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are spending $\$1000$, you want to guarantee winning more than $\$1000$ regardless of which player wins.

In order to win $\$1000$ for Player A winning, you would need to place a bet with Bookie 1 of $\frac{1000}{1.36}=\$735.294$

In order to win $\$1000$ for Player B winning, you would need to place a bet with Bookie 2 of $\frac{1000}{5.5}=\$181.818$

So to guarantee a profit, you should bet between $\$735.30$ and $\$818.18$ with Bookie 1 and the rest with Bookie 2.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! Is there a way however, to calculate the bets such that the profit is maximized?

Answer (score 1):

Your profit will be maximised if you bet everything on B and then B wins, giving a net gain of $\$ 4500$.  But it is not guaranteed, and is probably unlikely.  I do not think this is what you want

If instead you

- bet $\$1000 \times \dfrac{\frac1{1.36}}{\frac1{1.36}+\frac1{5.5}} \approx \$801.75$ on A
- bet $\$1000 \times \dfrac{\frac1{5.5}}{\frac1{1.36}+\frac1{5.5}} \approx \$198.25$ on B

then you bet $\$1000$ in total and

- if A wins you get $\$801.75 \times 1.36 = \$1090.38$ back
- if B wins you get $\$801.75 \times 5.5 = \$1090.375$ back

so either way a profit of just over $\$90$.  You cannot make your guaranteed profit any higher than that, since increasing your bet on option means reducing your bet on the other

Answer (score 0):

In general, suppose that you want to wager amount $A$ and the odds on two possible outcomes are $o_1$ and $o_2$. Let us denote by $A_1$ the amount you wager on the first outcome (with odds $o_1$) and $A_2$ the amount you wager on the outcome $o_2$.

So you know that 
$$A=A_1+A_2.$$ 
You also know that depending on the outcome, your winnings will be
\begin{align*}
w_1&=o_1A_1\\
w_2&=o_2A_2
\end{align*}

In order to maximize the profit *in each case*, you want $w_1=w_2$. (In other words, you won to bet in the way that you win the same amount, independently on the outcome.) So you need
$$o_1A_1=o_2A_2. \tag{1}$$

Now simply by algebraic manipulation you get
\begin{align*}
A&=A_1\left(1+\frac{o_1}{o_2}\right)\\
A&=A_1\frac{o_1+o_2}{o_2}\\
A_1&=\frac{o_2A}{o_1+o_2}
\end{align*}
and similarly
$$A_2=\frac{o_1A}{o_1+o_2}.$$

Another way to see this is not notice that $(1)$ says that $\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{o_2}{o_1}=\frac{1/o_1}{1/o_2}$, which basically says that you want to divide $A$ in the ratio $\frac1{o_1}:\frac1{o_2}$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
A_1&=\frac{\frac1{o_1}}{\frac1{o_1}+\frac1{o_2}}A,  
A_2&=\frac{\frac1{o_2}}{\frac1{o_1}+\frac1{o_2}}A. 
\end{align*}
Notice that this cen be simplified to
$$\frac{A_1}A
=\frac{\frac1{o_1}}{\frac1{o_1}+\frac1{o_2}}
=\frac{\frac1{o_1}}{\frac{o_1+o_2}{o_1o_2}}
=\frac{o2}{o_1+o_2}
$$
so both expressions give the same value, only expressed in a different way.

However, the second expression you can see more easily that you make profit if and only if $\frac1{o_1}+\frac1{o_2}<1$. Indeed, to make profit you need
\begin{align*}
A&<o_1A_1\\
A&<\frac{A}{\frac1{o_1}+\frac1{o_2}}\\
1&<\frac{1}{\frac1{o_1}+\frac1{o_2}}\\
\frac1{o_1}+\frac1{o_2}&<1
\end{align*}

For the particular numbers you need, you simply plug $A=1000$, $o_1=1.36$ and $o_2=5.5$ into the above formula.

I will add also a link to the Wikipedia article about [Arbitrage betting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage_betting).